# Kinematics Question?

Tags: kinematics

[image]

[image]

approach:

a) 
$d_{y} = v_{1y}t + 0.5at^{2}$

$680 = v_{1}\sin{57(6.20s)} - 188.55$

$v_{1} = 585 m/s$

im not sure if this is right.. any help is really appreciated!

B) not sure how exactly to apprach this :/

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is wrong. The distance $d_{y}$ is negative $=-680$. Then continue the way you have done.

For (B), Take $v_{x}$ the same way you took $v_{y}$. Can you proceed further now?